# SQL how to find rows which have highest value of specific column

Tags: sql, select, find, rows

For example, the table has columns MYINDEX and NAME.

```
MYINDEX | NAME
=================
1       | BOB
2       | BOB
3       | CHARLES
```

Ho do I find row with highest MYINDEX for specific NAME? E.g. I want to find ROW-2 for name "BOB".

Comment: Edited, for the love of god don't describe tables in prose.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`SELECT Max(MYINDEX) FROM table WHERE NAME = [insertNameHere]`

EDIT: to get the whole row:

```
Select * //never do this really
From Table
Where MYINDEX = (Select Max(MYINDEX) From Table Where Name = [InsertNameHere]
```

Comment: He wants the whole row, not just the max for that column

Comment: @Lucas Heneks: Not how I understood it pre-edit.  And neither did most of the first posters, so I tend to think mine was the correct interpretation when I wrote the answer.

Edit forthcoming to answer his actual question.

Comment: Upvoted your edit.  But...his original, unedited question "Ho do I find row with highest MYINDEX for specific NAME?" certainly requested the row :)

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT MAX(MYINDEX) FROM table
WHERE NAME = 'BOB'
```

For the whole row, do:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE NAME = 'BOB'
AND MyIndex = (SELECT Max(MYINDEX) from table WHERE NAME = 'BOB')
```

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to tackle this one. I'm assuming that there may be other columns that you want from the row, otherwise as others have said, simply name, `MAX(my_index) ... GROUP BY name` will work. Here are a couple of examples:

```
SELECT
    MT.name,
    MT.my_index
FROM
(
    SELECT
        name,
        MAX(my_index) AS max_my_index
    FROM
        My_Table
    GROUP BY
        name
) SQ
INNER JOIN My_Table MT ON
    MT.name = SQ.name AND
    MT.my_index = SQ.max_my_index
```

Another possible solution:

```
SELECT
    MT1.name,
    MT1.my_index
FROM
    My_Table MT1
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM
            My_Table MT2
        WHERE
            MT2.name = MT1.name AND
            MT2.my_index > MT1.my_index
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to see the highest index for name = 'Bob', use:

```
SELECT MAX(MYINDEX) AS [MaxIndex]
FROM myTable
WHERE Name = 'Bob'
```

Comment: I actually want to find ROW with highest index for name, not just the highest index for name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip the inner join, you could do:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NAME = 'BOB' ORDER BY MYINDEX DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
FROM TABLE SELECT MAX(MYINDEX), NAME GROUP BY NAME
```