# Select rows with highest value of multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL how to find rows which have highest value of specific column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337469/sql-how-to-find-rows-which-have-highest-value-of-specific-column)

Here is my table schema

```
--transaction_details--
transaction_id primary_key auto inc
entity_name 
entity_transaction
```

Now, one entity can have multiple transactions. I want to query last transaction made for *every* entity, which is unlike [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3337469/1220971) that looks up a specific column. This can be done by selecting the rows with last/max `transaction_id` for each entity. But I am unable to write this query. I tried using group by `entity_name` but its selecting any random row.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3337469/1220971

Comment: Naah, That giving result for a specific row, I want highest id row for every entity.

Comment: @Sourabh: So you will do the exact same thing except that your inner query will `GROUP BY entity_name`.

Comment: Well, as I wrote, I tried it, and group by is giving unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, if entity_transaction is always the same for the same entity_name:

```
select max(transaction_id), entity_name, entity_transaction
from transaction_details
group by entity_name, entity_transaction
```

If you can have different values for `entity_transaction` for the same `entity_name`, use this query:

```
select g.transaction_id, g.entity_name, d.entity_transaction
from
(
    select max(transaction_id) transaction_id, entity_name
    from transaction_details
    group by entity_name
) g
inner join transaction_details d
  on g.entity_name = d.entity_name and g.transaction_id = d.transaction_id
```

Comment: No its not the same, if it would be the same, why would I need a specific one.

Comment: @Sourabh: Well, obviously because of the transaction_id. Anyway, I added another version, please have a look and remove that downvote.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select * 
from   <table> t
join
     ( select entity_name,max(transaction_id) as transaction_id
       from <table>
       group by entity_name)a
on    a.entity_name=t.entity_name
and   a.transaction_id=t.transaction_id
```